# Disable Add Call option from CallKit

Tags: ios, ios10, callkit

Is there a way to disable Add Call option from **Callkit** when receiving a **VoIP** call?

I couldn't find any api to disable this. But WhatsApp disabled this feature.

Comment: The tags already indicate this is about iOS. There is no need to add "iOS" to the title.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the `supportsGrouping`, `supportsUngrouping` and `supportsHolding` properties to false in the `CXCallUpdate` for the call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will test and update the results.

Comment: Actually this is not enough. You also need to set `maximumCallGroups` and `maximumCallsPerCallGroup` to 1. The answer below should be accepted.

Comment: Can I open my custom app on answering the VoIP phone call? Please know me since I don't have iOS development experience. But curious to know this.

Answer (score 27):

You need to set both `supportsGrouping`, `supportsUngrouping` and `supportsHolding` properties to false in the CXCallUpdate, and set `maximumCallGroups` and `maximumCallsPerCallGroup` to 1 in your `CXProviderConfiguration`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It should be noted, though, that this configuration also hides the "hold-and-accept" option with call-waiting. It also prevents you from supporting any other functionality (like "assisted transfer") that depends on placing a call on hold. There doesn't seem to be a permutation of `CXProvider` / `CXCallUpdate` settings that _only_ disables the "add-call" button. If someone does know a workaround I'd be most grateful :)