# Hide FaceTime button in CallKit UI

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I'm implementing CallKit support inside a VoIP application.

I was able to disable video button by setting `supportsVideo` to `false` in `CXProviderConfiguration`. Now the FaceTime button appeared.

I wanted to know if there is a way to disable FaceTime button in the default UI, since the app is handling internal enterprise numbers which has nothing to do with FaceTime.

---

**Update**:
As stated in the answers below, it's possible to disable the button, but the caller number is lost (shown as `Unknown`). I want to preserve the number and disable the FaceTime button.

---

**Update**:
Disabling FaceTime in iPhone settings disables the FaceTime button. However it's not a valid solution to the issue.

---

**Update**:
Any changes to `CXHandle` type, including inserting characters not valid for a phone number into it, does not affect the issue - FaceTime button is still shown.

Comment: Did you find any new information about this issue since you last edited your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a good news/bad news vein, I was able to disable the FaceTime button by clearing `remoteHandle` (not removed or hidden, just grayed out).

However, as a side effect, the Caller shows up as "Unknown", if you don't set the `localizedCallerName` property of the `CXCallUpdate`.
A call without a handle will have the side effect of not being pressable in Recents.

```
CXCallUpdate *callUpdate = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
//callUpdate.remoteHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:handle];
[self.provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:uuid update:callUpdate completion:^(NSError* error) {}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think that your solution may be useful in other cases. I'm aware of that, but unfortunately we want to keep the number of the caller too. It's a phone number, it just has nothing to do with FaceTime and global phone network.

Comment: It doesn't have to say "Unknown". You can change the string it shows by setting the `localizedCallerName` property of the `CXCallUpdate`. But a call without a handle will have the side effect of not being pressable in Recents.

Answer (score 8):

I pulled my hair out for this problem, removing remoteHandle did disable the button, but you can't make call from System Call History anymore.

Finally figured out a perfect solution, I'd like to share.

Assume we support both Audio/Video.

1. Init `CXProviderConfiguration`.

   ```
   let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "yourConfigName")
   providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = supportsVideo
   providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.generic, .phoneNumber, .emailAddress] // Pick your own supportedHandleTypes.
   ```
2. Exclude `remoteHandle` when report incoming call.

   ```
   let update = CXCallUpdate()

   // Set hasVideo so it shows correct type on incomingCall screen.
   update.hasVideo = supportsVideo

   // Exclude remoteHandle so that the FaceTime button is disabled
   // update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: yourHandle)
   ```
3. **Important!** Update the remoteHandle when ending the call, in `func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction)` delegate.

Excluding the remoteHandle when reportIncomingCall will lose the ability to call from System Call History.
But you can update the call and set it up right before ending the call.

```
 func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {
    let update = CXCallUpdate()

    // Set the remoteHandle, so you can call from System Call History
    update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: yourHandle)
    provider.reportCall(with: uuid, updated: update)

    action.fulfill()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the FaceTime button disabled by following the same approach as for [disabling the "Add Call" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170810/disable-add-call-option-from-callkit), which doesn't break the caller name functionality, however weirdly the FaceTime button becomes active again if the user touches the speaker button. I don't see why would this behavior not be an Apple bug, so I just gave up on a proper fix.

edit: here's why: I was attributing a `CXHandle` to the `CXCallUpdate` only once the call was established, so at first the FaceTime button was disabled given that there was no `CXHandle`. Activating the speaker button somehow forced an update in the CallKit UI - at this point, there would exist a `CXHandle` already and thus the FaceTime button would get enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It's can really disable the FaceTime button by clearing remoteHandle as @Eli Burke says, but the side effect is disabling calling from Recents. I don't know why.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I just don't know why can't disable FaceTime button and enable calling from Recents in the meanwhile?