# To gray out the buttons in the call information page when using callkit

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, google-meet

How can I gray out (disable) the button on the call information page? 
 (Referring to the below pic please)

[image: Google Meet] [image: Normal CallKit]

I noticed It displays a blue button with enabled when using normal CallKit, as [Kodeco guide](https://www.kodeco.com/1276414-callkit-tutorial-for-ios). 
But I can't find any property or method to control the buttons in the call history detail information page.

Is there a way to gray out the buttons examples like google meet, Zoom, KakaoTalk?(Korean Service)

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245638/hide-facetime-button-in-callkit-ui?

Comment: Yes, but that guide is for handle button in on calling state. :(

Comment: Oh I tried that way with `CXHandle`'s type generic, It works. thanks very much @RoHan